# Windows Ruby/Rails IDE or editor with autocompletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ide, editor

I am looking for an IDE with Ruby on Rails autocompletion on windows. Netbeans seems to be ok but he is buggy and the wizard for importing existing project does not work. RubyMine is unable to read files from a network drive (and you must pay for it!).

Is there any Ruby ide autocompleting code with at least the rails API and eventually my project classes?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Aptana Studio 3 Beta](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3), that runs on [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/). One of it's features, RadRails, provides exhaustive support for both Ruby and Ruby on Rails.

Comment: It also recognizes HTML5 tags, which is one major reason I switched from RadRails 2. I got fed up with seeing omnipresent HTML5 "errors".

Comment: I played with aptana, but it does not seems to do autocompletion in the ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

Try [e editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/). The power of textmate on windows!